# how to detect horizontal scroll event in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two areas in my html. All two areas can only horizontal scroll. What I want to realize is, if I horizontal scroll one area, another area can get the same horizontal scroll offset. How to realize that in angularjs? I try to use

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('xxx')).bind('scroll', function() {
   ...
})
```

But it does no use. Anyone can tell me how?

Comment: It might help you.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this angular module.
[ng-scrollable](https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable)

It contains the spyX and spyY property where you can control the positions of the scrollbar. You could get the scrollbar position on the first html scrollable and bind it to the second one.